# Best solution to collapse list of object if necessary

Tags: java, performance, java-8, java-stream, filtering

today i am trying to collapse a list of objects if they have certain characteristics.
My idea is to definitely use stream().

Imagine an object made like this:

```
public class ObjectA {
     private Integer priority;
     private LocalDate date;
     private String string;
}
```

and I have a:

```
List<ObjectA> objects
```

I would like to collapse the objects in this list for objects that have the same date. If they have dates that fall within a specific time window, then only the one with the highest priority remains, if the priority are equal so the one with a specific constant in the attribute "string", the other is eliminated from the list.

Example, this:

```
 window = 1; // days
 constantString = "aab";
 [{"priority":1, "date":"2021-09-22", "aaa"},  
 {"priority":1, "date":"2021-09-23", "aab"}, 
 {"priority":1, "date":"2027-10-09", "bbb"}]
```

Became this:

```
[{"priority":2, "date":"2021-09-23", "aab"}, 
 {"priority":1, "date":"2027-10-09", "bbb"}]
```

What do you think is the best solution in terms of efficiency, considering that this list could have many elements.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: What does it mean if window value was 2? Do the objects having date of 22. Sep & 23. Sep fall in the same group?

Comment: Bad move to completely edit the specs after asking a question! What should happen if neither of the instances which have equal priority match the specific constant?

Comment: Exactly Eritrean. I'm sorry for that Adriaan, just i say many times. To answer your question instead, let's assume that it is not possible and it will be enough.

Comment: I suggest you attempt solving this yourself and if you have further problems with it, show us your  code.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it is an optimal solution, however, if you insist on using Stream API, you can achieve it with a bunch of collectors:

- **`groupBy`** to group by `date` into `Map<String, List<ObjectA>`.
- **`maxBy`** to reduce into a single object from `List<ObjectA>` with the highest `priority` (hence `Comparator`).
- Since the collectors above result in ugly `Map<LocalDate, Optional<ObjectA>>` use **`collectingAndThen`** to extract what you need back into `List<ObjectA>` using another Stream.

```
final String specificConstant = "ccc";

List<ObjectA> filtered = list.stream().collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
    Collectors.groupingBy(
            ObjectA::getDate,
            Collectors.maxBy(Comparator
                .comparing(ObjectA::getPriority)
                .thenComparing(objA -> specificConstant.equals(objA.getString())))),
    map -> map.values().stream()
            .filter(Optional::isPresent)
            .map(Optional::get)
            .collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

A full example with a result printed out into the console:

```
List<ObjectA> list = List.of(
    new ObjectA(1, LocalDate.parse("2021-09-22"), "aaa"),
    new ObjectA(2, LocalDate.parse("2021-09-22"), "aaa"),
    new ObjectA(2, LocalDate.parse("2021-09-22"), "ccc"),
    new ObjectA(1, LocalDate.parse("2021-09-09"), "bbb")
    );

final String specificConstant = "ccc";
        
List<ObjectA> filtered = list.stream().collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
    Collectors.groupingBy(
            ObjectA::getDate,
            Collectors.maxBy(Comparator
                .comparing(ObjectA::getPriority)
                .thenComparing(c -> specificConstant.equals(c.getConstant())))),
    map -> map.values().stream()
            .filter(Optional::isPresent)
            .map(Optional::get)
            .collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

```
[ObjectA(priority=1, date=2021-09-09, constant=bbb), ObjectA(priority=2, date=2021-09-22, constant=ccc)]
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I oversimplified the example, it's a bit more complex. I edited the question. Excuse me.

Comment: I have edited my answer. All you need is to expand the `Copmarator`. Please, next time complete minimal *and* complete sample.

Comment: you are right. my problem is being able to understand how to consider only the ObjectA whose difference in the dates is equal to or less than the value of "window" (days), it's possible with Comparator? Thanks for the patience.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you could do this using streams:

```
Collection<ObjectA> collapsed = values.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        ObjectA::getDate,
        Function.identity(),
        (a, b) -> a.priority < b.priority ? b : a))
    .values();
```

The Collectors.toMap method takes the following arguments:

```
Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,
Function<? super T, ? extends U> valueMapper,
BinaryOperator<U> mergeFunction
```

The keyMapper determines the map key, we use the date from ObjectA.
The valueMapper determines the map value, this is the ObjectA instance itself (identity function).
The mergFunction determines what happens when two values have the same key. We provide here a BinaryOperator which chooses the element with the highest priority.

EDIT: Whilst I was answering this, you completely changed the specs of the question!

Comment: perhaps I should have asked another question to better specify the cases. So sorry about it. your answer was correct!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in `O(n)` time, with `n` the number of elements in the list.

Convert the list to a HashMap with keys as the dates, values as the priority. Then when you hit an element with the same date as an element you've recorded, you can replace the value for that date key if the new value has a higher priority.

Then, you can convert the HashMap back into a list if you want.

Comment: I'm sorry, I oversimplified the example, it's a bit more complex. I edited the question. Excuse me.